# WPF application to web

Tags: wpf

I´ve got a WPF app running in a local PC witch I need now to be implemented for web. I read somewhere that a WPF app can be for desktop or for web...is that true? If it is, how can I make sure my actual project runs on web?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to do it. Microsoft itself has written a [beautiful article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480223.aspx) about it and [how to deploy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970060.aspx) it. But you might want to read about the differences between XBAP and Silverlight [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2008/05/06/when-should-i-use-wpf-vs-silverlight.aspx) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/811121/wpf-wba-xbap-versus-silverlight). Maybe XBAPs aren't the right solution for you.

Comment: thanks! that´s was helpfull.. but what I need is to convert an actual running WPF application to WPF browser application