# Is SilverLight web application and Xbap browser application is same

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xbap

I'm new to WPF and confused about the XBap browser application. I read that with the help of WPF we can make Windows stand-alone applications *and* Browser applications.

I am confused that an Xbap Browser application is also a Silverlight application yet it's different. If it's different then where do we use it?

Is it possible to convert an Xbap Application into a Silverlight web application?

Can anybody provide me a good link for this tutorial?

Comment: Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/811121/wpf-wba-xbap-versus-silverlight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you might be looking for, but this article provides a very good insight on xbap applications -

http://blog.wpfwonderland.com/2007/01/28/comparing-wpf-applications-and-xbap-whats-the-difference/

Don't forget to have a look at comments :)

Answer (score 3):

No, they are different.

XBAP is a deployment model for WPF. With XBAPs you get access to most of the .NET4 APIs, however it is a requirement that the end-user is running windows and has .NET3.5 / 4.0 client profile installed (75MBytes)

Silverlight is a subset of WPF that runs as a browser plugin. The API is not as rich as WPF, however, Silverlight applications can run on Windows & Mac OS. Also, the end-user only needs to install a plugin (5MBytes) to run a Silverlight application.